# Unable to create PHP extension with swig

Tags: php, c++, swig

I am trying to generate a PHP extension of a C++ program ([Simstring](https://github.com/chokkan/simstring)), but I am a little stucked.

The program already propose a python and a ruby extensions working with Swig.

I followed the [Swig PHP documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Php.html) but I got an error.

Here is what I have done and the result I got, maybe you can help me with that:

```
cd swig;
mkdir php;
ln -s ../export.cpp
ln -s ../export.h
ln -s ../export.i
swig -c++ -php -o export_wrap.cpp export.i
g++ `php-config --includes` -fPIC -c export_wrap.cpp
g++ -shared export_wrap.o -o simstring.so
sudo mv simstring.so my-php-extension-dir/
```

I load the extension in my php.ini but I got the following error :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/simstring.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/simstring.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6writer5closeEv in Unknown on line 0
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: you definitely missed some library to link with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @zaufi, I searched more and found the answer.

I was definitively missing a file.

The right commands are the followings (please note the `export_wrap.cpp` AND `export.cpp` resp. `export.o` AND `export_wrap.o`)

```
g++ `php-config --includes` -fPIC -c export_wrap.cpp export.cpp
g++ -shared export.o export_wrap.o -o simstring.so
```

For more informations, you have to "include" the simstring.php generated file.

Comment: +1 thanks, u saved my day, in php7 i only used .cxx file, didn't use .cpp together this is where i wrong